# Is it possible to recover deleted responses from Google Forms?

Tags: google-forms, data-recovery

Here is the context of this question. We used Google Forms for an election of 6 people. I want to know if it is possible to delete individual responses and then recover all responses (deleted and not deleted). For example, on Google Docs you can look at everyone's edits and recover deleted items from previous dates. Is this possible with Google Forms and if so, how can I get all of this information.

Comment: did you try **Version History**?

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't save the form responses to a Sheet before deleting them, they cannot be recovered after deletion.

I contacted Google support about this issue in the past and they told me the same thing - they don't have an undelete button for Forms.

Answer (score 2):

> **Yes you can get back deleted form Responses**

i know this is an old post but this answer is for anyone else looking for the same solution to a similar problem quite recently.

You might have some luck here- google has quite a good auto backup system when it comes to sheets

Login on your desktop browser for easier access

Your form responses are generally linked to a google sheet someplace - if you want to know which sheet name click on the green sheet logo on the right hand top corner of your google form settings  - it will ask you if you want to change the location of your responses "dont click anything " just make note of the sheet name that you see auto populated there.

Go to your google sheets in your google drive account & select that sheet that your form is linked to.

Click on "file" on the Menue

Click on "Version History > See Version History "

let it load

on the right hand side of the page you will see the diffrent auto saves done by google sheets - it includes everything that was inputed onto the google sheets -all data including that of the form, since the last time you accessed it.

Just tick the option "see changes" you will see all the changes done across the sheet in each and every timestamped version.

when you found what you looking for -clcik on "restore this version" get the data you need or deleted etc - it will all be saved here

take note this will restore your sheet back to the version you have selected based on the date & time of that auto backup you selected

Answer (score 0):

If it has been deleted from the bin. The only way to have access to the response is to recreate another one. It is done by clicking the three-dot button and selecting 'Select Response Destination' from here you will be offered to Create a New Spreadsheet or add the response to an old response database.

Answer (score -2):

If you still have the Form but without the Google Sheet response (deleted from trash), you may unlink the form and get a new spreadsheet later on with all the submitted response (Please know that the new spreadsheet will only contain response submitted from the latest version of Google Form).